# Plot of a piecewise function misbehaving

Tags: plotting, piecewise

Hi: I am trying to plot a piecewise function.  What's weird is that the plot either (a) does not appear at all, or (b) depending on settings, either appears as a horizontal/vertical time. I must be making a basic mistake. Here is the simplest version of the issue:

```
    U1[del_] = (1 - del)/del^{2}

    U2[del_] = 1 - (del (1 - del))/del^{2}

    U12P[del_] = Piecewise[{{U1[del], U1[del] >= U2[del]}}, U2[del]]
```

(So it should be the upper envelope of the two functions---taking U1 when it is higher and otherwise taking U2.)

I use:

```
    Plot[U12P[del], {del, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

which produces a horizontal line.  (Sorry, don't know how to make the image appear.)

But the problem does not appear when I just plot U1 and U2:

```
    Plot[{U1[del], U2[del]}, {del, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotLegends-> "Expressions"]
```

Looks as is should.

I looked but could not find my answer under other piecewise problems. In particular adding Exclusions->None did not help.  (Changed the problem slightly depending on the starting variant, but did not fix it.)

Comment: Curly braces (`{` and `}`) are reserved for forming `List`s in *Mathematica*. Remove the curly braces on the exponents (i.e. replace `{2}` with `2`) and it should work.

Comment: Putting curly braces around exponents is only a minor issue here. This question should be closed for that. The real problem is that `Piecewise` function is a single function and therefore can't produce the kind of label the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks---getting rid of the braces seems to do the trick!  sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `Piecewise` when you wish to retain the identity of the component functions in your plot. Try this.

```
U1[x_] := (1 - x)/x^2
U2[x_] := 1 - (x (1 - x))/x^2
Solve[U1[x] == U2[x], x]
```

> `{{x -> -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {x -> 1/Sqrt[2]}}`

```
u1[del_ /; del < N[1/Sqrt[2]]] := (1 - del)/del^2
u2[del_ /; del >= N[1/Sqrt[2]]] := 1 - (del (1 - del))/del^2

Plot[{u1[del], u2[del]}, {del, 0, 1}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is actually not what I was trying to do.  Let me try to re-express my question.